# two forms side by side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I started using Twitter Bootstrap and trying to place two forms side by side. By default if I place two forms on the page they follow one after another, what attribute should I apply to place these forms side by side with 50% width.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [grid features of twitter bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#gridSystem).
Something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6">
        <form>[...]</form>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <form>[...]</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT:

with Twitter Bootstrap 3.x

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form>[...]</form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <form>[...]</form>
    </div>
</div>
```

nb: in col-**sm**-6, `sm` stands for small, it means this grid will apply only for devices with  a viewport larger than `768px` (with TWBS default settings)

Comment: By using this layout, you **have** to fix the width of the inputs and labels, because the input grid will probably be bigger than a span6.